# Linux SNMP ifindex persistence

Tags: snmp

As we know Linux acts according RFC and does not make persistent SNMP if index entries. After reboot ifindexes re-renders.

I'm using Linux server as a router, so it has at least 7 logical interfaces, and after adding some new interfaces IfIndexes changes. So this is a problem for monitoring system, which uses snmp indexes as interface identifiers. The monitoring system we're using is Observium with Weathermap plugin.

Maybe someone know the viable workaround to Linux (Centos) system to make a persistence SNMP if index entries ?

Thanks

Comment: Sounds like an XY problem. What are you trying to do?

Comment: hello, sorry - i've updated the main message.  This is a problem for monitoring system, which uses snmp indexes as interface identifiers. Maybe you had some experience with it ? Thanks